# Missing Table Heading After apply DataTable to Complex span column and Row

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a plain table that has column span and row span as as below:

```html
<table border="1" id="">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th rowspan="2">No</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Branch</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Branch Code</th>
      <th colspan="2">Approval</th>
      <th colspan="2">Disbursement</th>
      <th colspan="2">Active Portfolio</th>
      <th colspan="3"># of Active Client</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Active Portfolio</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th># of loans</th>
      <th>$ of Loans</th>
      <th># of loans</th>
      <th>$ of Loans</th>
      <th># of loans</th>
      <th>$ of Loans</th>
      <th>Male</th>
      <th>Female</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Head Quarter</td>
      <td>HQ</td>
      <td class="text-right">19</td>
      <td class="text-right">220938/td>
      <td class="text-right">11</td>
      <td class="text-right">120938</td>
      <td class="text-right">11</td>
      <td class="text-right">9282726</td>
      <td class="text-right">10</td>
      <td class="text-right">1</td>
      <td class="text-right">11.00</td>
      <td class="text-right">0.263397549755</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td class="text-right">15</td>
      <td class="text-right">112121</td>
      <td class="text-right">7</td>
      <td class="text-right">12120</td>
      <td class="text-right">7</td>
      <td class="text-right">12121</td>
      <td class="text-right">6</td>
      <td class="text-right">1</td>
      <td class="text-right">7.00</td>
      <td class="text-right">12121</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-bold">
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-right">115</td>
      <td class="text-right">21212121</td>
      <td class="text-right">54</td>
      <td class="text-right">134343</td>
      <td class="text-right">54</td>
      <td class="text-right">4232</td>
      <td class="text-right">43</td>
      <td class="text-right">11</td>
      <td class="text-right">54</td>
      <td class="text-right">8.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, I would like to applied `DataTable` to above table following the instruction [here](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tbList').dataTable();
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table border="1" id="tbList">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th rowspan="2">No</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Branch</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Branch Code</th>
      <th colspan="2">Approval</th>
      <th colspan="2">Disbursement</th>
      <th colspan="2">Active Portfolio</th>
      <th colspan="3"># of Active Client</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Active Portfolio</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th># of loans</th>
      <th>$ of Loans</th>
      <th># of loans</th>
      <th>$ of Loans</th>
      <th># of loans</th>
      <th>$ of Loans</th>
      <th>Male</th>
      <th>Female</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Head Quarter</td>
      <td>HQ</td>
      <td class="text-right">19</td>
      <td class="text-right">220938/td>
        <td class="text-right">11</td>
        <td class="text-right">120938</td>
        <td class="text-right">11</td>
        <td class="text-right">9282726</td>
        <td class="text-right">10</td>
        <td class="text-right">1</td>
        <td class="text-right">11.00</td>
        <td class="text-right">0.263397549755</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>NY</td>
      <td class="text-right">15</td>
      <td class="text-right">112121</td>
      <td class="text-right">7</td>
      <td class="text-right">12120</td>
      <td class="text-right">7</td>
      <td class="text-right">12121</td>
      <td class="text-right">6</td>
      <td class="text-right">1</td>
      <td class="text-right">7.00</td>
      <td class="text-right">12121</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-bold">
      <td>Total:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="text-right">115</td>
      <td class="text-right">21212121</td>
      <td class="text-right">54</td>
      <td class="text-right">134343</td>
      <td class="text-right">54</td>
      <td class="text-right">4232</td>
      <td class="text-right">43</td>
      <td class="text-right">11</td>
      <td class="text-right">54</td>
      <td class="text-right">8.01</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However, the problem is the table heading that has attribute `colspan` and `rowspan` are missing leaving data unfitted with column heading.

What was wrong to my table and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Very simple typos... There is an extra <tr> </tr> in the <thead> part of the table. Remove that. Also in the first row if data, there is improper </td> tag. Correct these two things and it displays properly.

Comment: @T.Shah, ah to my bad, how come I messed up this, thanks very much that fixed.